# How can I accelerate the following for loop in Python?

Tags: python

I need to calculate the distance between each pair of points as stored in two numpy arrays, and apply a function on the distance. The following is the core code:

```
# xcoords, ycoords are two 2D arrays, with size (nx = 50, ny = 50)
xcoords_ = xcoords.flatten()
ycoords_ = ycoords.flatten()
C = np.zeros(shape = (nx*ny, nx*ny))
for ipt1 in range(nx*ny):
    for ipt2 in range(nx*ny):
        if ipt2 > ipt1:
            xpt1 = xcoords_[ipt1]
            ypt1 = ycoords_[ipt1]
            xpt2 = xcoords_[ipt2]
            ypt2 = ycoords_[ipt2]
            if cov_type == 'exponential':
                c = Cov_Exp(xpt1 - xpt2, ypt1 - ypt2, corlen_x, corlen_y, sigma**2)
                C[ipt1, ipt2] = c
    C[ipt1, ipt1] = 1e-8
```

The called function is defined as:

```
def Cov_Exp(xlag, ylag, corlen_x = 1.0, corlen_y = 1.0, sigma2 = 1.0):
    d = (xlag / corlen_x)**2 + (ylag / corlen_y)**2
    c = sigma2*np.exp(-np.sqrt(d))
    return c
```

I found the for loop is very slow. How can I accelerate it? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a combination of [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`np.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) to create two "blown-up" matrices, one likes tiles placed next to each other, another one where each number is repeated next to each other:

[image]

This way, you can directly subtract both matrices from each other, without needing to loop through each element:

```py
xcoord_tiled = np.tile(xcoords, (nx, ny))
xcoord_repeated = np.repeat(np.repeat(xcoords, nx, axis=0), ny, axis=1)

ycoord_tiled = np.tile(ycoords, (nx, ny))
ycoord_repeated = np.repeat(np.repeat(ycoords, nx, axis=0), ny, axis=1)

xlag = xcoord_tiled - xcoord_repeated
ylag = ycoord_tiled - ycoord_repeated

c = Cov_Exp(xlag, ylag)
```